# value assigned to `right` is never read

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust so I may be confused or ignorant but I couldn't find an answer for my situation or field in my search at least.

This is my code:

```
fn main() {
    let sorted_array: [i32; 10] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let target: i32 = 3;
    let mut left: usize = 0;
    let mut right: usize = 10;
    while left <= right {
        let middle: usize = (left + right) / 2;
        if sorted_array[middle] == target {
            println!("Target index {middle}");
            break;
        }
        if sorted_array[middle] > target {
            right = middle - 1;
            break;
        }
        if sorted_array[middle] < target {
            left = middle + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
warning: value assigned to `right` is never read
  --> src/main.rs:13:13
   |
13 |             right = middle - 1;
   |             ^^^^^
   |
   = help: maybe it is overwritten before being read?
   = note: `#[warn(unused_assignments)]` on by default
```

But I am using these variables at

`let middle: usize = (left + right) / 2;`

Doesn't it count as a read? if not what is counted as a read? and how can I wright this code correctly?

I am still trying to learn, so I will be thankful for an answer.

I tried to find the same mistake but all the questions had a workaround or the compiler complained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't want the `break` in the second and third `if` statement. The compiler is pointing out that you assign a value to `right`, then the loop is immediately exited, thus the value is never read again.

Comment: you are right ... it didn't come to my mind ... thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

A break is used to exit a loop.
[Breaks and Continues](https://google.github.io/comprehensive-rust/control-flow/break-continue.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20exit%20a%20loop%20early%2C,is%20used%20to%20break%20out%20of%20nested%20loops%3A)

So you are assigning the value to right `right = middle - 1`
Then immediately breaking out of the surrounding while loop and reaching the end of the function.

The same thing will happen with the section of code

```
if sorted_array[middle] < target {
    left = middle + 1;
    break;
}
```

So unless you do something with `right` and `left` after the loop; you'll continue to get that warning whenever you are in those if statements.

You might be looking to do something like:

```
fn main() {
    let sorted_array: [i32; 10] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let target: i32 = 3;
    let mut left: usize = 0;
    let mut right: usize = 10;
    while left <= right {
        let middle: usize = (left + right) / 2;
        if sorted_array[middle] == target {
            println!("Target index {middle}");
            break;
        }
        if sorted_array[middle] > target {
            right = middle - 1;
        }
        if sorted_array[middle] < target {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are hoping to stay in the while loop until the `sorted_array[middle] == target` and you execute that print statement.

Comment: thanks for your time. i don't know why i put break in the first place.
i understand now how why rust is so loved :D